# C++ separating std::strings by space

Tags: c++

I have a `std::string line = "!l1 l2 l3"` and I want to separate this string by the spaces, remove the '!' and inserting l1, l2 and l3 into 3 `std:strings` l1_sep, l2_sep and l3_sep.
l1, l2 and l3 can be values with up to 3 chars.

Input Examples: `"!50 125 5"` or `"!5 60 50"` or `"!100 7 123"`

Output desired: `std::string l1_sep= l1, std::string l2_sep= l2 and std::string l3_sep= "l3",`

Right now I have tried:

```
std::size_t l1_pos = line.find(" ");
std::string l1_sep= line.substr (l1_pos);
```

This makes the `l1_sep="!l1"` but how can I remove `the '!' and get the l2 and l3?

PS: if there is a way where l1_sep, l2_sep and l3_sep are other types of variable besides std::string, I can change it

Comment: In C# this would be really easy, but in C++ you will need to write your own parser.

Comment: What's stopping youi from comparing the first character to `!`?

Comment: I can compare, but I can't delete it. And to compare I have to change this string into a std::vector<char> or not?

Comment: Can you explain why you "can't delete it"? `std::string`s are perfectly capable of deleting stuff from them. Happens all the time.

Comment: what do you mean regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add safety checks to make sure the string follows the pattern yourself.

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

void parse(string line, string & l1, string & l2, string & l3)
{
    // todo: insert your safety here; throw exceptions as necessary.

    line.erase(0, 1);

    auto space = line.find(' ');
    l1 = line.substr(0, space);
    line.erase(0, space + 1);

    space = line.find(' ');
    l2 = line.substr(0, space);
    line.erase(0, space + 1);

    l3 = std::move(line);
}
```

Usage:

```
string line;
// assign line
string l1, l2, l3;
parse(line, l1, l2, l3);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! Just had to make a small change from space+1 to space in the l2=line.substr(0,space+1); Really really appreciate it!

Comment: @Bia I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(){
    std::string line = "!l1 l2 l3";
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::string l1_sep;
    std::getline(iss, l1_sep, ' ');

    // check the first character of l1_sep
    // if it is `!` then erase it
    if (l1_sep[0] == '!') {
        l1_sep.erase(0, 1);
    }

    std::string l2_sep;
    std::getline(iss, l2_sep, ' ');

    std::string l3_sep;
    std::getline(iss, l3_sep, ' ');

    std::cout << "l1_sep : " << l1_sep << std::endl;
    std::cout << "l2_sep : " << l2_sep << std::endl;
    std::cout << "l3_sep : " << l3_sep << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could simply have the `stringstream` ignore the `!` Instead. And use `operator>>` to read space-separated words. No need to use `std::getline()` at all.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is not critical, use [regular expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex):

```
const std::regex regex(R"(!(\S{1,3})\s+(\S{1,3})\s+(\S{1,3}))");
// or
// const std::regex regex(R"(!(\d{1,3})\s+(\d{1,3})\s+(\d{1,3}))");

std::string line = "!5 60 50";
if (std::smatch match; std::regex_match(line, match, regex)) {
    const auto l1_sep = match[1].str();
    const auto l2_sep = match[2].str();
    const auto l3_sep = match[3].str();

    std::cout << l1_sep << '\n';  // prints 5
    std::cout << l2_sep << '\n';  // prints 60
    std::cout << l3_sep << '\n';  // prints 50
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever whitespace-delimited data needs to be extracted, `operator>>` is the first thing that comes to my mind. In this case, you can use `std::istringstream` to parse a string, like this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string line = "!l1 l2 l3";
std::string l1_sep, l2_sep, l3_sep;
std::istringstream iss(line);
iss.ignore(); // skip ‘!’
iss >> l1_sep >> l2_sep >> l3_sep;
```